# How can I secure my account where only numbers are allowed as password?

Tags: passwords, http

The website of China Southern Airline FFP only accepts 6 to 10 number digits as its password and no letters are accepted. Furthermore, it is still running on plain HTTP but not HTTPS!

How can I prevent my FFP account being hacked on such website?

Comment: Those restrictions allow 10,000,000,000 permutations - sound like a lot but actually is fairly trivial to crack with a desktop PC bruiting it in a few minutes http://password-checker.online-domain-tools.com/. The lack of HTTPS is a significant worry and surprising, have you tried to force it to HTTPS yourself in the address bar?

Comment: Not significant, perhaps, but it allows for 11,111,000,000 permutations.  10,000,000,000 only accounts for the possibilities that are exactly ten digits long.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that site is not using best practices for both passwords and SSL, it's safe to say there's probably other areas they haven't secured. In a perfect world I would say dont use that site but I'm assuming you need to.

Personally I would look to email their support and check whether there are any other more secure ways of doing what you need to do, but if you absolutely have no choice but to use the site then use a password generator such as [this](https://passwordsgenerator.net/) to create the strongest password you can and try to limit what information you put onto the site where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a lot of options, unfortunately.  There are a couple of things that you need to do:

- Pick the longest (10 digit) strongest (randomly generated) password you can.
- Change it as frequently as possible.
- **NEVER** access the site from an untrusted network.  This means never use public wifi to access it, for starters.

The last thing I'd recommend is to minimize the amount of value an attacker can get out of the account.  Don't store credit card or bank account info.  Use your frequent flyer miles as often as you can.  This way, if the account *is* compromised because of their poor practices, you'll have reduced the amount of damage that can be done as much as reasonably possible.

Answer (score -3):

Since the login page is on an insecure HTTP link (unencrypted), anyone on the local network can "sniff" your password. You need to go through a VPN or use an HTTPS proxy to connect to the server. Beware of using a rogue HTTPS proxy on the Internet though, many times they cannot be trusted. Alternatively, consider using a private browser such TOR that is geared towards security and privacy.

If they are forcing you to use numbers and on an HTTP page, they obviously do not care about security. I would write their IT / security team an email urging them to put SSL encryption to secure login credentials. Any login page demanding user credentials over unsecure HTTP connections is not acceptable.

Also see:

- https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en
- https://www.sslproxies.org/
- https://openvpn.net/

Comment: Using plain HTTP over Tor is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Arminius other than the exit node's ability to modify anything from my request and the server's response, what dangers does HTTP over Tor imply?

Comment: @SaAtomic That's what I was hinting at. With Tor it's not just possible, but [very likely](https://chloe.re/2015/06/20/a-month-with-badonions/) that an exit node is capturing the traffic. Therefore, Tor doesn't solve OP's problem at all but makes it worse.